# How to boot ubuntu off an SDXC card

Tags: boot, bios, sd-card

I'm wondering if anyone can help with this issue.

I currently have an Asus UX303LA, on this laptop I plan on leaving Windows on my ssd and installing Ubuntu on a Lexar 128 GB SDXC card for the ability to boot into a Linux environment.

So far this is what I've done

I've played around with the BIOS setting, turned off Fast boot, enabled CSM, disabled secure boot control. My laptop seems to have no problem recognizing USB drives and even booting off of them, but unfortunately it doesn't recognize the SD card in the BIOS. I've tried to work my way around it and mounted the ISO on a USB drive, then install the OS on the SD card (which worked) but unfortunately if the BIOS doesn't recognize the SD card off the start, then it cannot boot the newly installed environment. I've then looked at the manufacturer website to see if I can flash my BIOS, but it seems that it's already installed the latest version.

I've also noticed that somehow my computer has recognized some form of linux installation off my SSD, so while booting into it it takes me to a GNU GRUB command line. While trying to restore the Linux installation through command line, it does not recognize the SD card as one of the Hard drive sources.

I can see/access and do what I'd like to my SD card in any GUI environment.. But without loading into an environment, seems like I can't access my SD card.

Does anyone have a solution for me other than using a USB drive or buying an external SD card reader?

Answer (score 0):

Other than using a USB reader I dont think there is much of a solution to be honest. I know for my own laptop it WILL NOT read the card on boot unless I put it into an external reader. After the bios hands off to the OS its completely different. The OS has drivers for the media drive and accepts it as its own source. The bios however, only accepts USB and the other standard set of things.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the directory /boot on the SSD (or whatever internal storage device you have)? You would need to make space for it. I would guess that about 100MB would do. I haven't tried it yet but intend to try with a new Windows laptop. (Grub-efi would also have to be on the internal storage.)

Do you think it would work?